# I can't change an HTML element's contents through the callback to the jquery function $.getJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, openweathermap

I'm trying to change the content of the div element with **id** attribute *country* (i.e. `id="country"`) to the country of the user's current position. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
function location (position){
    var a=position.coords.latitude;
    var b=position.coords.longitude;    
    $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='+a+'&lon='+b+'&APPID=b84cde4a2b80a14ecfebbd9ea7d08831&units=metric', function getData(data){
      $("#country").html(data.sys.country);
    }) 
  }
```

Comment: Your Javascript looks ok.  What happens if you add a `console.log(data.sys.country)`?  Is it the value you expect?

Comment: Adding to @machineghost's comment. If it doesn't work, try logging the whole returned JSON.

Comment: if i add console.log(data.sys.country) it says "data is not defined".

Comment: so inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network and see what actually gets returned in the response body. Or build the same url manually and put it into browser address bar

Comment: i checked the whole thing out - its perfect.  The only point of failure could be the `position` parameter, since the code that is generating it isnt included.  It could also be that the `location(position)` function is never actually being triggered in the script -- or a javascript error somewhere else in the chain is preventing it from firing

Comment: see my latest edit

Comment: thanks alot mike510a and every1 else u were right it was the position object problem.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

An important thing to mention is that As of Chrome 50, the Geolocation API will only work on secure contexts such as HTTPS.

If your site is hosted on an non-secure origin (such as HTTP) the requests to get the users location will no longer function.

If your using HTTPS then,

**ORIGINAL**

I'm guessing your not building your position object correctly.

Make sure that you have a `position` object, which has a property called `coords` with a value of an object with two properties, latitude and longitute.  Every object has to be encapsulated with  `{ }`

It works great in this snippet (original code unchanged):

```js
function location(position) {
  var a = position.coords.latitude;
  var b = position.coords.longitude;
  $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + a + '&lon=' + b + '&APPID=b84cde4a2b80a14ecfebbd9ea7d08831&units=metric', function getData(data) {
    $("#country").html(data.sys.country);
  })
}

/* here we build our position object with a coords child object containing latitude and longitude */
var pos = {
  "coords": {
    "latitude": 34.7459360,
    "longitude": -118.2506350
  }
};

/* now we actually call the script  location(pos)  using our position object */
location(pos);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="country"></div>
```